# URL to the root directory of your site not saving (blank)

Tags: system

In the global configuration:

URL to the root directory of your site
This is the directory containing your site index file.

will not save. The form field is blanks. I had this error in 2.8.1 and have updated to latest hoping to fix the issue but it still exists.

Any ideas?

I've double checked permissions on folders and files.

Comment: I know you said above that you've checked permissions on files but just quickly make sure that the config.php file is writeable as that may be the problem here. If you have done that already then apologies for stating something you've already done. Just mentioned incase it was possibly overlooked.

Comment: Thank mark I thought that would be the issue too, but I double checked and I can save any other variable just not that specific one.